# Unknown right margin showing up on mobile page only

Tags: css

While using my computer everything works well but once I test on my phone, I get a weird margin on the right, I changed the body background color to black & the margin's color is now black so I guess it comes from the body tag.

[image]

I can't give whole CSS code +1000 lines but here are the lines affecting margin / body

I tried to set body `margin` & `padding` to `0` but nothing.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-height: 400px) {
  body {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="open">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="layer"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
    <section>
      <div class="header">
        <h2 class="logo">Fallen Angels</h2>
        <i class="fa fa-bars x2" onclick="menuToggle()" />
        <ul id="navbar">
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Boosting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <i class="fa fa-times x2" onclick="menuToggle()"></i>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="bannerText">
        ...
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected changing body's `width` to fix it but it just reduced the size of the whole thing including the `margin` :/
website preview : http://preview.fallen-angels.ga/

Comment: Please post your HTML also

Comment: by looking at the screenshot you provided, id say that the wrapper of the content above the footer is not 100%, can you pls provide the relative css ? i assume the is the wrapper and wrap class

Comment: removed the whole wrapper class and wrap but still :/

Comment: if you are so sure its the body tag. remove everything in it and run the app on your phone. If it is still that way then you can say its the body tag. otherwise let us decide whats wrong. You don’t have to submit all your code only relevant, isolated part.

Comment: added website preview for you guys to check for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly with this problem, I usually inspect the elements one by one. The problem with your case is this element:

```
<img src="assets/img/Xpreview.png" width="140%" style="padding-right: 40%;">
```

In small screens, the `col-md-6` width is 100%. Padding right 40% add 40% of the element's width to the image. That's why it exceeds the screen width, and adds the extra space there. 
You can use `style="max-width:100%"` to fix your problem. 
So at you can write this instead:

```
<img src="assets/img/Xpreview.png" width="140%" style="max-width:100%">
```

Comment: Love you too, #nohomo